# setOnItemSelectedListener of Spinner does not call

Tags: android, spinner

I used **setOnItemSelectedListener** to specify which item is selected in a spinner, but i think it is not called. it should print "It works" when the program runs.

XML code:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/quantity"
    android:layout_width="94dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_x="11dp"
    android:layout_y="118dp"
     />
```

Java code:

```
public class quantity extends Activity
{

Spinner  quantity;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    quantity=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.quantity);

    quantity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
            {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
                {
                    Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

                    System.out.println("it works...   ");

                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
                {

                }
            });


    }

}
```

Comment: did you call setContentView(R.layout.<yourXmlFile>) before doing findViewById

Comment: As @chopchop suggested you may be getting nullpointerexception. you have not set the content of your layout to the activity

Comment: Yes i did, but to make code shorter i omitted it here

Comment: any errors or exceptions assuming you have setContentView(param);

Comment: Do you have setted any data (array) for your spinner, i don't see any?

Comment: @Muhammad Babar you mean items to add in the spinner?
and there is no error

Comment: Yes, are you setting **adapter** of your `Spinner`?

Comment: @Muhammad Babar yes, but to make the code short and understandable i omitted them

Comment: is your **logcat** working??

Comment: another question: how many items do you have? I realized, that if an item is selected, you could not select it again. So if you got only one item, that is gonna be selected on init the spinner, but there will be no output if you select it again.

Comment: @Muhammad Babar Sorry dear you were right, i mistakenly never add data to spinner, Thanks for your solution

Comment: Good to hear you got it working :)

Comment: @Muhammad Beacuse of my low reputation i can not answer my question
so plz write an answer. I think it will be useful for novice people like me

Comment: Accept AT_AB's answer, seems correct!!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Your_Layout);

        //to fill your Spinner
        List<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        spinnerArray.add("Item 1");
        spinnerArray.add("Item 2");
        spinnerArray.add("Item 3");
        spinnerArray.add("Item 4");
        spinnerArray.add("Item 5");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Object item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if (item != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @KamyarParastesh if you had already solved the problem, it would be nice for your to share the answer with everyone, lest individuals spend time solving a problem for you that you have already solved.

Comment: setOnItemSelectedListener worked for me under the onCreate method. It does not work outside the UI Thread.

Answer (score -2):

you have missed setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

Comment: You should have added that as a comment and not as an answer.