# How to add a Spinner value along with previous calculated answers into a new calculation?

Tags: java, android, spinner

So this is my first app not following a tutorial. I have got the xml all laid out, spinner drop downs working also the first calculation working which is done by EditText numbers. 
I am now wanting to use this first calculated answer along with one of the spinner selected values to do the next calculation
Here is my xml

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inside"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Inside Ø \n(mm)"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/outside"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Outside Ø \n(mm)"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/coils"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Number of Coils"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/thickness"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/width"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_calculate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="calculate"
    android:text="Calculate" />

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="24dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_m"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_kg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_m2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/clear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="clear"
    android:text="Clear" />
```

And here is the code

```
package com.example.android.engineerstoolbox;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.android.engineerstoolbox.R.id.result_kg;
import static com.example.android.engineerstoolbox.R.id.result_m;
import static com.example.android.engineerstoolbox.R.id.result_m2;

public class CoilCalculator extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editText1;
    private EditText editText2;
    private EditText editText3;
    private Spinner spinner1;
    private Spinner spinner2;

    private TextView resultM;
    private TextView resultKG;
    private TextView resultM2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_coil_calculator);

        //set spinner1 for user input of available thickness
        Spinner dropdown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.thickness);
        String[] items = new String[]{"Thickness", "1.2", "1.5", "2", "2.5", "3", "4"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

        //set spinner2 for user input of available width
        dropdown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.width);
        items = new String[]{"Width", "1219", "1500", "1524"};
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inside);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.outside);
        editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.coils);
        resultM = (TextView) findViewById(result_m);
        resultKG = (TextView) findViewById(result_kg);
        resultM2 = (TextView) findViewById(result_m2);

        //Set button to do calculations
        Button bt_calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_calculate);

        bt_calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                makeCalculations();
            }
        });
        //Set reset button to reset inputs
        Button mButtonReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);

        mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editText1.setText("");
                editText2.setText("");
                editText3.setText("");
                resultM.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    private void makeCalculations() {
        double n1 = Double.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
        double n2 = Double.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());
        double n3 = Double.valueOf(editText3.getText().toString());

        //do the Lineal meter calculation
        Double calculatedValue = ((((n1 + n2) / 2) * 3.141592654) * n3) / 1000;
        double output = (double) Math.round(calculatedValue * 1000) / 1000;
        //set the value to the textview, to display on screen.
        resultM.setText(output + " Lineal Meters");

    }

}
```

I know i need to set a listener of some sort to pick up the spinner value; but i am unsure where and so far i have not found a question on here that explains where to put the code.

The next calculation would look something like this

```
    Double calculatedValue2 = output * (value of spinner2/1000);
    //set the value to the textview, to display on screen.
    resultM2.setText(calculatedValue2 + " M²");
```

I am pretty sure the double is not the way to go but wanted to show something for the next calculation

Comment: simply use spinner.getSelectedItem()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not actually assigned spinner1 and spinner2 to your Spinner objects.

```
    //set spinner1 for user input of available thickness
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.thickness);
    String[] items = new String[]{"Thickness", "1.2", "1.5", "2", "2.5", "3", "4"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

    //set spinner2 for user input of available width
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.width);
    items = new String[]{"Width", "1219", "1500", "1524"};
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then when you want to perform the calculation,

```
String selectedItem = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
double selectedValue = Double.parseDouble(selectedItem);
Double calculatedValue2 = output * (selectedValue/1000);
//set the value to the textview, to display on screen.
resultM2.setText(calculatedValue2 + " M²");
```

Comment: I knew would be something simple and overlooked; I now get a display onscreen except it is just the "output" from the first equation it is not doing the  *(selectedValue/1000)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a listener when you are selecting a value from the spinner, you should use Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener method. You can see this post for further information.

[setOnItemSelectedListener of Spinner does not call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581536/setonitemselectedlistener-of-spinner-does-not-call)

You just had to overwrite the onItemSelected method.