# How to get the index of string-array

Tags: android, spinner

In `strings.xml` I have `string-array` which populates the `spinner`.
I have an note app where user can select subject from spinner and show in recycler view.
So after user added note and if the user clicks the note then it should redirect to that spinner and auto select the subject which is selected previously.

I tried to set position as  `sub_spinner.setSelection(subPosition)` but I can't figure out how to get the `subPosition`

String.xml

```
<string-array name="subject">
    <item>Communication English</item>
    <item>Computer Graphics</item>
    <item>COA</item>
    <item>Data Communication</item>
    <item>Instrumentation II</item>
    <item>Software Engineerinng</item>
</string-array>
```

So if I have sub as COA then i should get index of 2.

Comment: try this `List<String> list= Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.subject));` you must add this list to ArrayAdapter, and set this adapter to spinner. Overrride the OnItemSelected method on this spinner there youll get position of item clicked. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581536/setonitemselectedlistener-of-spinner-does-not-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the subject `string-array` in the xml. You can get the string array in your java code by using

```
List<String> list= Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.subject));
```

Then in order to get the index of the selected subject, you can can implement an `OnItemSelectedListener` on the `Spinner` or `ListView`; anything that you have populated your string array on.

The `OnItemSelectedListener` implementation has a callback like `onItemSelected` with parameters, you want the `position` which provides the position of the selected item. Then you can do:

```
setSelection(position)
```

inside of the `OnItemSelectedListener`.  If you need further guidance on how to implement, you can post some more code and I will provide you the exact code to do this.