# "setOnItemSelectedListener()" not called when selecting item in spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

I'm creating an android app which is used for hotel management.

I want to show the user, the number of rooms available in the form of spinner.

I'm storing the details(roomNumber, name address etc..) in google firebase.

If the user is logging in the app for first time then all the room numbers in spinner should be visible. But if the user has already booked a room then that room number should not be visible in spinner.

Here is the java code:

```
documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
               if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                   roomNumberDocument=documentSnapshot.getString("RoomNumber");
                   if(roomNumberDocument!=null){
                       for (int i = 100; i < 111; i++) {
                           if(Integer.parseInt(roomNumberDocument)==i){
                               continue;
                           }
                           roomNumbersList.add(Integer.toString(i));
                       }
                   }else{
                       //room numbers
                       roomNumbersList.add("100");
                       roomNumbersList.add("101");
                       roomNumbersList.add("102");
                       roomNumbersList.add("103");
                       roomNumbersList.add("104");
                       roomNumbersList.add("105");
                       roomNumbersList.add("106");
                       roomNumbersList.add("107");
                       roomNumbersList.add("108");
                       roomNumbersList.add("109");
                       roomNumbersList.add("110");
                   }

               }
           }
       });
```

If the room is already booked then `roomNumberDocument` will not be null else it will be null.

If the room is already booked then I will not add it into the ArrayList `roomNumbersList`.

Here I'm setting up the adapter:

```
adapterRoomNumbers= new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, roomNumbersList);
        adapterRoomNumbers.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerRoomNumber.setAdapter(adapterRoomNumbers);
```

Here is the click listener for the spinner:

```
spinnerRoomNumber.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                strRoomNumber= adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+strRoomNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i(TAG, strRoomNumber);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

The problem is that `setOnItemSelectedListener()` is not called if I select any item in the spinner.

Because of that `strRoomNumber` is getting null. I will use `strRoomNumber` for storing it in the firebase database.

Here is my full [code](https://wtools.io/paste-code/b2eI)

What might be the problem?

Comment: Try move the codes for setting up the adapter to just before `documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener .......` and inside **onSuccess** method, add this as the last line: `adapterRoomNumbers.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: It worked! Can you put this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try move the codes for setting up the adapter to just before `documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener .......` and inside **onSuccess** method, add this as the last line: `adapterRoomNumbers.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Explanation: Adapter is not updated correctly as calls to firebase is an async process.

Comment: hey can help here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537639/spinner-value-using-retrofit-and-viewmodel#64537639

Answer (score 0):

your `setOnItemSelectedListner` must look like this:

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                int i, long id) {
            strRoomNumber = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString;
            if (item != null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+strRoomNumber,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(TAG, strRoomNumber);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

also check this out for more info
[setOnItemSelectedListener of Spinner does not call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581536/setonitemselectedlistener-of-spinner-does-not-call)

Comment: The above code isn't working!! In my code `setOnItemSelectedListner` is not called